# iLife Slideshows screen saver not working after update to macOS High Sierra 13.13.3

Tags: macos, screensaver

My screen saver - that shuffles between a list of files in a folder - have stopped working after I updated to 13.13.3. When the screen saver starts it shows a black screen with the following message:

"You cannot use the iLife Slideshows screen saver with this version of macOS. Please contact the vendor to get a newer version of the screen saver."

[image: screen shot of the screen saver not working]

Also my screen saver preference pane have stopped working - it simple does not switch to that screen when I click the "Desktop - Screen saver" button.

I have tried setting the screen saver using the terminal and the defaults command to update the plist file.

Comment: Look in your ~/Library/Screen Savers/ directory for the likely culprit. Deleting / moving it should restore your ability to access System Preferences for Desktop / Screen Saver (a restart may be necessary).

Comment: Thanks @DocG. The ~/Library/Screen Savers/ is empty - what does that mean?

Comment: It means my suggestion was wrong. I am sorry to have wasted your time. I hope you find a solution soon.

Comment: @DocG. No worries - all input is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up reinstalling my OS, so it's a solution, a bit drastic perhaps, but very effective.

Answer (score 1):

So happy!!!! Based on the tip from @DocG,

1. I went into my Hard Drive (at the bottom of the Finder left hand list) > Library > Screen Savers and moved that folder to the Trash.
2. Then I went into one of my Timemachine backups from a time when I was able to tap into my Photos and selected that same folder from within Timemachine and clicked Restore.

And voilà! My own wonderful photos are back & flipping around my screen saver.